# Removing punctuation/symbols from a list with Python except periods, commas

Tags: python, normalization

In Python, I need to remove almost all punctuation from a list but save periods and commas. Should I create a function to do this or a variable? Basically I want to delete all symbols except letters (I've already converted uppercase letters to lowercase) and periods and commas (and maybe apostrophes).

```
#Clean tokens up (remove symbols except ',' and '.')

def depunctuate()
   clean_tokens = []

   for i in lc_tokens:
       if (i not in [a-z.,])
       ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import string

# Create a set of all allowed characters.
# {...} is the syntax for a set literal in Python.
allowed = {",", "."}.union(string.ascii_lowercase)

# This is our starting string.
lc_tokens = 'hello, "world!"'

# Now we use list comprehension to only allow letters in our allowed set.
# The result of list comprehension is a list, so we use "".join(...) to
# turn it back into a string.
filtered = "".join([letter for letter in lc_tokens if letter in allowed])

# Our final result has everything but lowercase letters, commas, and
# periods removed.
assert filtered == "hello,world"
```

Comment: This not only removes unwanted (punctuation) symbols, but also whitespace and non-ASCII letters, turning words like "naïve" into "nave".

Comment: Yes, this only allows ASCII lowercase letters plus the few mentioned punctuation characters. That was my interpretation of the requirements, but it's highly dependent on what the questioner meant when using the word "letters." The other answer has a similar issue; it removes things in `string.punctuation`, but it's unclear whether that covers all the "symbols" the original questioner would like to remove.

Comment: You are right, `string.punctuation` also lacks a lot of punctuation symbols, eg. fancy quotation marks. Still, I think "letters" and "punctuation symbols" are pretty well-defined categories (and actually pretty easy to check through the Unicode character properties).

Answer (score 2):

You can build a set of unwanted punctuation from [`string.punctuation`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.punctuation) - which provides a string containing punctuation, and then use a *list comprehension* to filter out the letters contained in the set:

```
import string

to_delete = set(string.punctuation) - {'.', ','} # remove comma and fullstop
clean_tokens = [x for x in lc_tokens if x not in to_delete]
```